# Using Variables inside Hugo Data

Tags: variables, hugo, templating

I have been trying to learn Hugo and have a basic site running.
As well as the basic post data structure, I also have images loaded in each post by calling `.File.BaseFileName` to get the slug of the page and having relevant images named in the static folder.

Alongside the information in each post, I would like to augment each post with information from the data folder and have tried a similar technique of naming a data file the same as the slug (as I did with images in the description above).

However, when coming to reference this, using `{{.Site.Data.User0123.Name}}` from the [example page](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/) I need to pass a variable name to replace `User0123`

I have tried using:

1. The javascript style bracket syntax - `{{.Site.Data.["Variable"].Name}}`
2. declaring a variable of the slug and then using `{{.Site.Data.$slug.Name}}`

But neither of these worked.

I know I could put all additional info insdiode the post itself but this doesnt work for the flow I'm using, where the posts are generated automatically and I want to augment with additional data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague actually helped me this - seems the way to solve it, is to use the [`index` function.](https://gohugo.io/functions/index-function/)

```
{{ $userData2 := index .Site.Data $slug }}
  <div>boop2 {{$userData2.Name}}: <p>{{ index $userData2 "Short Description" | markdownify }}</p></div>
```